# How to globally configure secure clients using OpenSSL on Oracle Linux 5/RHEL 5?

Tags: rhel, openssl, ssl, tls, oracle-linux

My workplace recently patched one of our servers to address the POODLE vulnerability. Since then older Oracle Linux 5 clients (based on RHEL 5) can no longer securely connect to the server with any application. The client computers use OpenSSL version 0.9.8e; installing the latest available version of OpenSSL on these computers (0.9.8e-31) doesn't make a difference, but forcing the client to use only TLSv1 **does** fix the problem.

For example, `s_client` yields this:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect foo.bar.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
5529:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:188:
```

However, this works properly:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect foo.bar.com:443 -tls1
```

Similarly, `wget https://foo.bar.com/testFile` fails but `wget --secure-protocol=TLSv1 https://foo.bar.com/testFile` works.

My primary question is, how can I globally configure OpenSSL on these client machines so that they can connect again **without** having to manually reconfigure every single application we use or may use in the future. Upgrading these boxes to newer versions of Linux is not an option. Bonus points if you can explain what exactly is causing this behavior.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First, why?  In the [docs for `s_client`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/s_client.html) it's stated that openssl will by default use a handshake that figures out the correct protocol for you.  This is the whole basis of the POODLE attack.  The issue is that in 0.9.8 that handshake starts off with SSL_V23 and at some later point will try TLSv1 .  Many servers don't like it when clients connect using SSL_V23 because it's a red flag that the client is doing something insecure, hence your problem.

How to fix it?  Well, I couldn't find any option for openssl.cnf that would allow you to say "Hey, by default just use TLSv1".  In [this thread](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/Disabling-SSLv2-td17719.html), they seem to suggest this is possible in v1.0.0+.  After an hour of google searching, I decided your best bet is to [re-compile openssl and disable SSLv2 and SSLv3](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation#Configure_Options).  If you are recompiling openssl, it will probably be way easier to use 0.9.8, trying to upgrade openssl to 1.x+ in something like RHEL could be a total nightmare.

Comment: I explained why in the question. Unfortunately, `s_client` is just a program to test securely connecting to a server and does not affect other apps which use OpenSSL. I'm also aware of how the handshake process works which is how I knew to test with just TLSv1.

Comment: I also saw those two pages when I searched for an answer. If you read further, the thread you mention does not provide a viable solution. And there's no way we're going to recompile SSL on production systems and have to go through the certification process ourselves. It would be much less onerous to upgrade the system, which I already said is not an option.

Comment: Yes I get that s_client is just for testing, that's why I removed part of my answer earlier.  The thread I linked to wasn't intended to provide a viable answer, I was just showing evidence that the functionality you seek is not available until later versions of openssl.  Your original question didn't say anything about not re-compiling, which is your only option besides upgrading.  We're not magic!

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I was hoping there was some way to configure all apps that use OpenSSL with the default options at once, but I guess I'm out of luck. I imagine this is not implemented/allowed because it might open the door to security issues. Thanks for the effort anyway.

Comment: I don't think it's for security, I just don't think anyone thought about it prior to openssl 1.x .  Apache mod_ssl allows you to do this in the module's configuration.  I totally get why re-compiling SSL sounds like a big pain-in-the-butt, but I honestly think it would be way easier than upgrading the whole OS.

Comment: The big issue is that we'd have to remember to do it every time a new update came out. This would get old very quickly, especially if the code needed to be re-certified every time as some vendors require for secure transactions. I also assumed (but I could be wrong) that since many apps link against OpenSSL and alter their configuration based on OpenSSL's configuration, you would have to rebuild those apps as well to ensure they continue to work properly. For example, `wget` may change its config when compiling based on if OpenSSL supports SSLv3. That would be a lot of apps to recompile.

Comment: Long story short, I'd much rather updates were a distro's responsibility than my responsibility. I'm lazy. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since RHEL 5 suffers from the same problem, I just checked their bugzilla: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1152789

They focus pretty much on Tomcat 6 and their JBoss stuff, where this boils down to changing a few lines in the application server config.

But within that bugzilla there is a thread leading to the openssl-problem of RHEL5.

https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2014-1653.html

openssl-0.9.8e-31.el5_11 is the upstream recompiled openssl you need.

So:  IMHO you just need to install that patch AND force your web/application servers not to use insecure protocols.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. I've figured it out and I'll post an answer in a bit.

Comment: @AlvinThompson Did you find a better answer to this?